# Why is my JavaScript RGB Hex converter not working?

Tags: javascript, html, hex, rgb, converters

I made a RGB Hex converter in JavaScript. But my code is not working.

My problem: "First I typed a hex in hextxt input. Then, I pressed Hex to RGB button to convert my hex to rgb. But it is not working."

Here is my codes:

```js
function rgb_to_hex() {
    var r = +rtxt.value;
    var g = +gtxt.value;
    var b = +btxt.value;
    var rhex1 = r.toString(16);
    var ghex1 = g.toString(16);
    var bhex1 = b.toString(16);
    var hex1 = "Hex: #" + rhex1 + ghex1 + bhex1;
    p.innerHTML = hex1;
}

function hex_to_rgb() {
    var hex2 = +hextxt.value;
    var rhex2 = hex2.charAt(0) + hex2.charAt(1);
    var ghex2 = hex2.charAt(2) + hex2.charAt(3);
    var bhex2 = hex2.charAt(4) + hex2.charAt(5);
    var rgb = "RGB: " + rhex2 + ", " + ghex2 + ", " + bhex2;
    p.innerHTML = rgb;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="rtxt" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="gtxt" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="btxt" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="hextxt" />
<br>
<button onclick="rgb_to_hex()">RGB to Hex</button>
<br>
<button onclick="hex_to_rgb()">Hex to RGB</button>
<p id="p"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+hextxt.value` code is incorrect. The correct code is `hextxt.value`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function rgb_to_hex() {
    var r = +rtxt.value;
    var g = +gtxt.value;
    var b = +btxt.value;
    var rhex1 = r.toString(16);
    var ghex1 = g.toString(16);
    var bhex1 = b.toString(16);
    var hex1 = "#" + rhex1 + ghex1 + bhex1;
    document.getElementById("hextxt").value = hex1;
}

function hex_to_rgb() {
    var hex2 = hextxt.value;
    var rhex2 = hex2.charAt(1) + hex2.charAt(2);
    var ghex2 = hex2.charAt(3) + hex2.charAt(4);
    var bhex2 = hex2.charAt(5) + hex2.charAt(6);

    document.getElementById("rtxt").value=parseInt(rhex2,16);
    document.getElementById("gtxt").value=parseInt(ghex2,16);
    document.getElementById("btxt").value=parseInt(bhex2,16);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="rtxt" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="gtxt" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="btxt" />
<br>
<input type="text" id="hextxt" />
<br>
<button onclick="rgb_to_hex()">RGB to Hex</button>
<br>
<button onclick="hex_to_rgb()">Hex to RGB</button>
```